# PostgreSQL UUID type performance

Tags: postgresql, indexing, hash, uuid

I'm not trying to restart the UUID vs serial integer key debate. I know there are valid points to either side. I'm using UUID's as the primary key in several of my tables.

- Column type: `"uuidKey" text NOT NULL`
- Index: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX grand_pkey ON grand USING btree ("uuidKey")`
- Primary Key Constraint: `ADD CONSTRAINT grand_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("uuidKey");`

Here is my first question; with PostgreSQL 9.4 is there any performance benefit to setting the column type to UUID?

The documentation  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-uuid.html  describes UUID's, but is there any benefit aside from type safety for using this type instead of `text` type? In the character types documentation it indicates that `char(n)` would not have any advantage over `text` in PostgreSQL.

> Tip: There is no performance difference among these three types, apart
>   from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a
>   few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a
>   length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance
>   advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage
>   in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the
>   three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text
>   or character varying should be used instead.

I'm not worried about disk space, I'm just wondering if it's worth my time benchmarking UUID vs text column types?

Second question, hash vs b-tree indexes. No sense in sorting UUID keys so would b-tree have any other advantages over hash index?

Comment: If you are creating an unique index in addition to the primary key it is not necessary. When you set a primary key an unique index is created on the key.

Comment: I may have shown it in the wrong order. The index was automagically created by the primary key constraint.

Comment: It also seems, according to the docs (at the time of this comment 9.4 being the latest stable version), that the use of hash indexes are discouraged: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-types.html

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood something about this post, but why would you use TEXT when Postgres has a native UUID column type?  Are there any benefits to TEXT at all?

Comment: The UUID column type was added in 9.0. This database was first created in 8

Answer (score 68, accepted):

We had a table with about 30k rows that (for a specific unrelated architectural reason) had UUIDs stored in a text field and indexed. I noticed that the query perf was slower than I'd have expected. I created a new UUID column, copied in the text uuid primary key and compared below. 2.652ms vs 0.029ms. Quite a difference!

```
 -- With text index
    QUERY PLAN
    Index Scan using tmptable_pkey on tmptable (cost=0.41..1024.34 rows=1 width=1797) (actual time=0.183..2.632 rows=1 loops=1)
      Index Cond: (primarykey = '755ad490-9a34-4c9f-8027-45fa37632b04'::text)
    Planning time: 0.121 ms
    Execution time: 2.652 ms

    -- With a uuid index 
    QUERY PLAN
    Index Scan using idx_tmptable on tmptable (cost=0.29..2.51 rows=1 width=1797) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
      Index Cond: (uuidkey = '755ad490-9a34-4c9f-8027-45fa37632b04'::uuid)
    Planning time: 0.109 ms
    Execution time: 0.029 ms
```

Answer (score 54):

A `UUID` is a 16 bytes value. The same as `text` is a 32 bytes value. The storage sizes are:

```
select
    pg_column_size('a0eebc999c0b4ef8bb6d6bb9bd380a11'::text) as text_size,
    pg_column_size('a0eebc999c0b4ef8bb6d6bb9bd380a11'::uuid) as uuid_size;
 text_size | uuid_size 
-----------+-----------
        36 |        16
```

Smaller tables lead to faster operations.

Comment: But how it react when it comes to uuid comparison. Is there any benefit using uuid over int

Comment: MAX(uuid_column) isn't supported, so that's a real difference.

Comment: @AllainLalonde Why would you want that?

Comment: A discussion of max(uuid) can be found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275251/why-is-there-no-maxuuid-minuuid-function/305274#305274 – there are some use cases and it can easily be added as an aggregate function