# How to create a UUIDField in Django that doesn't require the default func to be provided, instead returns UUID generated by the DB?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Currently the top answer for [How does a Django UUIDField generate a UUID in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210753/how-does-a-django-uuidfield-generate-a-uuid-in-postgresql) says

> When you use `UUIDField` as a primary key in Django, it doesn't generate a UUID one for you, you generate it yourself before you save the object

But I think it should be possible to hack a solution that allows for DB-based UUID generation.

Once you have installed `uuid-ossp` extension in postgres

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

I think it should work more or less like an `AutoField`.

If a raw sql has been used for the table creation

```
CREATE TABLE example(
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
);
```

Then raw insert will return a new random UUID as an id field.

How would one go about creating a custom `Field` so this raw solution works with Django ORM?

Comment: Why do you feel this step is necessary, what do you think you will gain by transferring UUID generation on database

Comment: There are cases when I need to check if object is new. So far I did `self.pk is None`. I think `self._state.adding` is not 100% reliable. Another option is `FieldTracker` from `model-utils` but it comes with a performance hit and using a proxy model only for that is an overkill.

Comment: you can omit default from your UUID primary and set it inside of save method instead, this way self.pk wont be set for new records prior to entering into save method

Comment: As I'm gonna put that in a Mixin I will have to make sure MRO is in the proper order but yes, that's a neat trick. I'll do that, thanks!

Comment: Furthermore you can specify pre_save hook to generate uuid automatically just a moment before you actually save. See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/ It sounds much simplier than adding a new field with custom interface to db.

Comment: I'm not a fan of signals but yes, that's also a clean solution. Will consider that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run into the solution for this question I asked a year ago. Django provides you with [`RandomUUID`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/functions/#randomuuid) which calls `gen_random_uuid` in PostgreSQL.

Example usage:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.functions import RandomUUID

class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID)
```

Where `RandomUUID` is

```
class RandomUUID(Func):
    template = 'GEN_RANDOM_UUID()'
    output_field = UUIDField()
```

For version below 13 [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgcrypto.html) mention that calling `gen_random_uuid`

> Returns a version 4 (random) UUID. (Obsolete, this function is now also included in core PostgreSQL.)

It's obsolete as "obsolete in pgcrypto" extension.

In PostgreSQL docs for version 13 and above you can find [this function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-uuid.html) being mentioned under [Chapter 9. Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions.html)
 section.

> This function returns a version 4 (random) UUID. This is the most commonly used type of UUID and is appropriate for most applications.