# What is the performance hit of using a string type vs a uuid type for a UUID primary key?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, indexing, primary-key, uuid

Is there much of a speed difference for index lookups by using `string` for the primary key versus the actual `uuid` type, specifically if the string has a prefix like `user-94a942de-05d3-481c-9e0c-da319eb69206` (making the lookup have to traverse 5-6 characters before getting to something unique)?

Comment: I think the difference in speed between two string indexes with slightly different lengths is insignificant.  If you really care, then add auto-increments/serial columns to your tables and use integers for the indexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL UUID type performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880083/postgresql-uuid-type-performance)

Comment: @GordonLinoff UUIDs are only strings on MySQL. They're stored as numbers in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Schwern A different, but related, question is being asked.

Comment: @Steve Ah. Umm... AFAIK MySQL doesn't have a UUID type, and I'm not sure why you wouldn't use the PostgreSQL UUID type. Could you clarify why you're sking?

Comment: In MySQL, simple function can convert a UUID into a `BINARY(16)` (16 bytes, 128 bits), which save space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance difference between UUID, CHAR, and VARCHAR in PostgreSql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189129/performance-difference-between-uuid-char-and-varchar-in-postgresql-table)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a micro-optimization and is unlikely to cause a real performance problem until you get to enormous scales. Use the key that best fits your design. That said, here's the details...

[UUID is a built in PostgreSQL type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html). It's basically a 128 bit integer. It should perform as an index just as well as any other large integer. As of Postgres 13 it offers [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) to make [UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) (basically just a random number). For more functions you can load the [uuid-ossp extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html), or you can generate a UUID in the client. Generating the UUID on the client distributes the extra work (not much extra work) away from the server.

MySQL does not have a built in UUID type. Instead there's [UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) which can generate a [UUIDv1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) as a string of hex numbers. Because it's a string, UUID keys may have a performance and storage hit. It may also interfere with replication. You can use [UUID_TO_BIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-to-bin) to turn that into a `varbinary(16)`; effectively a 128 bit integer.

The string UUID will be longer; hex characters only encode 4 bits of data per byte so a hex string UUID needs 256 bits to store 128 bits of information. This means more storage and memory per column which can impact performance.

Normally this would mean comparisons are twice as long, since the key being compared is twice as long. However, UUIDs are normally unique in the first few bytes, so the whole UUID does not need to be compared to know they're different. Long story short: comparing string vs binary UUIDs shouldn't cause a noticeable performance difference in a real application... though the fact that MySQL UUIDs are UTF8 encoded might add cost.

Using UUIDs on PostgreSQL is fine, it's a built-in type.

MySQL's implementation of UUID keys means you have to do a lot of conversion between strings and varbinary, which welcomes bugs, and by using UUIDv1 which has some mild security implications.

Comment: The string version of uuid normally has 4 dashes, hence `CHAR(36)`.

Comment: [PostgreSQL 13 introduced gen_random_uuid()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-uuid.html) to avoid the need to install [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) just to get a random (v4) UUID - though that module remains available if you need other versions or functions.

Answer (score 7):

The real problem with UUIDs comes when the table (or at least the index) is too big to be cached in RAM.  When this happens, the 'next' uuid needs to be stored into (or fetch from) some *random* block that is *unlikely* to be cached.  This leads to more and more I/O as the table grows.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` ids *usually* don't suffer that I/O growth because `INSERTs` always go at the 'end' of the table and `SELECTs` *usually* cluster near the end.  This leads to effective use of the cache, thereby avoiding the death-by-IO.

My [*UUID blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) discusses how to make "Type-1" UUIDs less costly to performance, at least for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in UUID type that maps to a 128-bit int. Not just for performance, but to prevent strings like "password1" from showing up in that column.